# Circular arrangement question

Tags: combinatorics

A teacher and 12 students (6 boys and 6 girls) are sitting around a circular table.  In how many ways can these 13 indiciduals sit if out of the 12 students no two boys or no two girls sit next to each other ?

---

My attempt :-

Firstly, I made all the 6 boys sit on the 6 chairs such that no 2 of them are together, these 6 boys can be arranged in 6! ways.  There will be 6 gaps created in total, in which there will be 1 gap having 2 seats and rest of the 5 gaps will have 1 seat.  Now I can place the 6 girls into these 6 gaps in 6! ways, and the last seat will automatically be assigned to a teacher.

so as per my understanding it should be 6!*6! ways

however the official answer is given as 2*6!*6! ways

How is this factor of 2 coming in ?

Comment: Easier to seat the teacher first. Then the circle becomes a line, and the boys either occupy all the odd-numbered seats, or all the even-numbered seats, with the girls sitting where the boys aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First fix the teacher as reference at the north seat

Now seating them clockwise, it has either to be
BGBGBGBGBGBG or GBGBGBGBGBGB

Hence the factor of $2$, yielding $2*6!6!$ arrangements

Comment: Thank you ! but can you let me know what is the fault in my answer as well please?

Comment: In your method also, the $2$ factor will arise at the two seat vacancy. B - - B can be filled in two ways BGTB or BTGB

Comment: @trueblueanil how will the first permutations for boys be 6! as in circular permutations it should be (6-1)!=5!

Comment: @XZCY: I placed the teacher as reference point, so w.r.t. the teacher, the boys will have $6!$ permutations.

Comment: @trueblueanil I cannot figure out the flaw in my solution, can you help me spot it?

Comment: @XZCY: I have explained below your answer.

Comment: though since you mention "north", if we take their physical positions into account, there should be an additional factor of 13

Comment: @ilkkachu: This is not an actual north, just a  so called "north" that fixes one seat. That is why in a simple circular seating, the number of arrangements are $(n-1)!$, or alternatively, $\dfrac{n!}{n}$ so you *could* write the answer of this question as $13\cdot 2\cdot6!6! /13$ which comes to the same thing, but why make it more complicated ?

Comment: @trueblueanil because I'm not talking about the relative order between the individuals, or a factor of 13/13, but of an actual physical seating order and a factor of 13 that comes from where the pivot person is physically seated. I also never claimed you were talking about that, just that you mentioned the word "north". The question only asks for the number of "ways" to seat the 13, which doesn't appear to specify exactly if they're only interested in the relative positions or not. (Of course I'm still assuming the seats themselves have fixed positions.)

Comment: @ilkkachu: *Unless specifically mentioned* that the seats are numbered, it is taken that seats are unnumbered in circular seating.

Comment: @trueblueanil, perhaps you take it that way. In any case that doesn't contradict my statement that if we take the physical positions into account, an additional factor of 13 is needed. I'm not sure why you're arguing about irrelevant matters, instead of e.g. pointing out some actual flaws in what I stated.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Of course, I agree that direction can always be identified by a wall, door, or at the worst, a compass, and if we take that into account, $n$ people at a circular table can be seated in $n!$ ways, *but circular permutations are not treated like that* See, for example,  https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Applied_Mathematics/Applied_Finite_Mathematics_(Sekhon_and_Bloom)/07%3A_Sets_and_Counting/7.04%3A_Circular_Permutations_and_Permutations_with_Similar_Elements . If they are treated differently in your country, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

If you seat boys first then it would be $(6-1)! = 5!$

(As for circular permutations it would be $(n-1)!$)

[image]

Now if you decide to seat girls next then it would be $2*6!$ as they can seat as shown below

[image]

> Reason: As every girl is a unique person their relative position matters with respect to boys. (I haven't number every person,if you do so it would be more clear)

And then the final seat goes to the teacher,

**But any of the six boys could seat adjacent to the teacher so we multiply by $6$.**

Hence the final answer is $\fbox{2*5!*6!*6= 2*6!6!}$

Comment: In your second diagram, you have shown the vacant seat as B-G or G-B, which takes care of the $2$ factor. *but the boy adjacent to the teacher could be any of the* $6$, so the correct answer becomes $2*5!6!\times6 = 2*6!6!$ But it is so much simpler to first place the teacher as a refernce point !

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: Why are we not considering whether 
the teacher will be left or right from the boy as well?

Comment: @Fin27: the *two* vacant seats in the diagram take care of that.

Comment: @Fin27 Refer to 2nd figure $\\$... In that in case 1 one of the boy has a vacant seat to the right and in 2nd case one of the boy has vacant seat to the left, so for that boy when we consider 2 cases we consider the teacher seating to his right as well as left. And after that we multiplied by 6 to this to take into consideration for all 6 boys.